# Set up a subscription for messages with no matching filter in Azure Service Bus (on-premise)

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I'm using [Azure Service Bus 1.1 (the on premise version)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn282144.aspx)

I'm trying to set up a subscription that will receive messages that have not been filtered into any other existing subscription.

I have 3 console apps, one that creates topics and subscriptions, one that sends messages to the topic, and one that receives messages from a subscription.

I'm also using the [Service Bus Explorer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a) (V2.1) to see what is happening with my console apps.

I have tried setting up the topic as described on [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2012/04/16/integration-patterns-utilizing-the-windows-azure-service-bus-part-ii.aspx) and [this page](http://convective.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/windows-azure-appfabric-service-bus-queues-and-topics/) which uses a `MatchNoneFilterExpression` but the example code does not compile(?) ie the FilterAction and FilterExpression properties **are not in the RuleDescription class**

```
         RuleDescription matchNoneRule = new RuleDescription()
         {
             FilterAction = new SqlFilterAction("set defer = 'yes';"),
             FilterExpression = new MatchNoneFilterExpression()
         };
```

The RuleDescription class I'm using is in v2.1.0.0 of the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
It has the following properties available,

[image]

How do I send a message that matches no other filters to a particular subscription?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this page](http://blog.codit.eu/post/2012/07/16/Service-Bus-for-Windows-server;-an-introduction.aspx) which suggests setting the `EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing` property on the topic.

It then suggests that on sending a message to this topic a message will trigger the `NoMatchingSubscriptionException`

I'm creating my topic with this code

```
var myTopic = new TopicDescription(topicName)
{
    EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing = true
};
namespaceManager.CreateTopic(myTopic);
```

I'm sending a message to the topic that doesn't match any filters and I can catch the exception and potentially resend the message with a property that does match a filter, e.g.:

```
try
{
    topicClient.Send(message);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message sent: Id = {0}, Body = {1}", message.MessageId, message.GetBody<string>()));
}
catch (NoMatchingSubscriptionException ex)
{
    string messageBody = message.GetBody<string>();                        
    BrokeredMessage msg = new BrokeredMessage(messageBody);
    msg.Properties.Add("Filter", "NoMatch");
    foreach (var prop in message.Properties)
    {
        msg.Properties.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
    }
    topicClient.Send(msg);

    Console.WriteLine("\n NoMatchingSubscriptionException - message resent to NoMatchingSubscription");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message sent: Id = {0}, Body = {1}", msg.MessageId, msg.GetBody<string>()));
}
```